# Ansible module to attach an IAM role to existing EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to attach an `IAM` role to multiple EC2 instances based on tags. Is there a module already available which I can use. I have been searching for a bit but couldn't find anything specific.

Answer (score 2):

Attaching an IAM role to existing EC2 instances is a relatively new feature (announced in Feb 2017). There is no support for that in Ansible currently. If you `AWS CLI 1.11.46` or higher installed, then you can use `shell` module to invoke the AWS CLI and achieve desired result.

See: [New! Attach an AWS IAM Role to an Existing Amazon EC2 Instance by Using the AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/new-attach-an-aws-iam-role-to-an-existing-amazon-ec2-instance-by-using-the-aws-cli/#comment-3161127199)

Comment: Thanks for the info @helloV.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/21336) last year to add 2 AWS modules : `boto3` and `boto3_wait`.

These 2 modules allow you to interact with AWS API using boto3.

For instance, you could attach a role to an existing EC2 instance by calling [`associate_iam_instance_profile`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.associate_iam_instance_profile) method on EC2 service :

```
- name: Attach role MyRole
  boto3:
    service: ec2
    region: us-east-1
    operation: associate_iam_instance_profile
    parameters:
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Name: MyRole
      InstanceId: i-xxxxxxxxxx
```

Feel free to give the PR a thumbs-up if you like it! ;)

In addition to this, you can use [AWS dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) to target instances by tag.